# explicit uniformizer for the false Tate extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $n\geq 1$. Set $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^n})$,
$L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p^n]{p})$, and $M=KL$. I claim that $M$ is totally ramified of degree $\phi(p^n)p^n$ (the proof simultaneously shows that $K$ and $L$ are linearly disjoint). Assume not, then there exists an unramified extension $W\subseteq M$ with $[W:\mathbb{Q}_p]=f>1$ ($f$ being necessarily a power of $p$). By the structure theorem for unramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we know that $W=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{r})$
where $r=p^f-1$. The extension $K$ is totally ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and therefore linearly disjoint from $W$. We thus have
$$
\mathbb{Q}_p\subseteq K \subsetneqq KW \subseteq M=K(\sqrt[p^n]{p})
$$
By Galois theory, since $f>1$, it follows (this also holds true if $K$ and $L$ are not linearly disjoint) that $\sqrt[p]{p}\in KW$ and therefore
$\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{p})\subseteq KW$. But $KW$ is abelian over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{p})$ is not. Contradiction.

**Q1**: How to construct (systematically in $p$ and $n$) an explicit uniformizer of $M$ (for $n>1$ of course)?

**Q2** Is it possible to find some uniformizer $\pi'$ of $K$ (so $v_p(\pi')=\frac{1}{\phi(p^n)}$) such that $K(\sqrt[p^n]{\pi'})=M$ (for $n>1$ of course) ?

**Remark:** Note that Q2 is equivalent to find (by Lagrange's resolvent) $\beta\in M$ such that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{p^n-1} \sigma^j(\beta)\zeta_{p^n}^j,
$$
is a uniformizer of $M$. Here $\sigma$ is a generator of $Gal(M/K)$. This seems to boil down to some difficult linear algebra.

Comment: On Q1 only: I’ve never been able to answer somewhat more difficult questions of this type, but for what I wanted, I found that I didn’t need to hold a uniformizer of $M$ in my hand. Is Q1 motivated by some other question, or is it for you simply an intrisically interesting question?

Comment: Yes Q1 is actually motivated by a problem of one of my colleagues, and yes, most likely he won't need to hold an explicit uniformizer. Nevertheless, I thought the question so natural that I could not resist to post it on MO.

Comment: As for __Q1__ I was still thinking about it. As a first approach I tried to pin down a uniformizer $\varpi$ of $K$ such that $M\subseteq L_{\varpi,p^n}$ (in Lubin-Tate's notation). My second step would be to understand how does $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ act on $G_{\varpi,p^n}$ in order to identify the stable $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-lines with respect to this action, since $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ would be one of those. But I am stuck on the first point...

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer to question **Q2** is **no**. Indeed, Lemma 3 of Birch's paper in *Cassels and Fröhlich* tells us that two extensions $k(\sqrt[n]{a}),k(\sqrt[n]{b})$ of a field $k$ (of characteristic prime to $n$, and) containing a primitive $n$-th root of unity, coincide if and only if
$$
a=b^r\cdot c^n
$$
with $(r,n)=1$. In your setting, if we had $K(\sqrt[p^n]{p})=K(\sqrt[p^n]{\pi'})$ for a suitable uniformiser $\pi'$ of $K$, taking $\pi'$-adic valuations would give
$$
\phi(p^n)\equiv r\pmod{p^n}
$$
for a suitable $r$ prime to $p$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

I gave this question to a student as a summer project. Thanks to Mercio's answer to a similar question posted on StackExchange (link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954731/ ) we have worked out how to find explicit uniformizers of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^2},\sqrt[p]{p})$ for all odd p. We have written a short article on our calculations, which can be found here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01656 Please let us know if you have any suggestions and/or comments for us.